# Set disabled a set of input

Tags: forms, symfony, collections, twig

I have a nav-tab page where is display my form (with CollectionType).

for some reason, I need to display some input from the form of the second tab inside the first one.

For now I've done this go the the fields :

```
    {% set speTC = [] %}
{% set speG = [] %}
{% for classe in form.classe %}
    {% set className = classe.vars.value.nom %}
    {% for matiere in classe.matieres %}
        {% if className == "sub1" %}
            {% set speG = speG|merge([matiere])  %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if className == "sub2"  %}
            {% set speTC = speTC|merge([matiere])  %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
            {{ form_start(form) }} ...some stuf...{{ form_end }}
```

But I have this as a deprecation :

> You are calling "form_widget" for field "name" which has already been rendered before

Which is unerstandable, but I need to get **[matiere]** formView inside my second tab (where usually I need to render it in my last tab)

How to I remove those deprecation ?

Comment: I'm really astonished how you managed to keep almost all relevant information out of your problem description. The error message though is quite clear.  I assume / hope, you're calling `form_widget(form)` at the `...some stuf...`(sic) location. if you do, try `form_rest(form)` instead. *However*, only form elements that are inside the form_start ... form_end will be considered when submitted from the browser (unless javascript does some magic)

Comment: You can only render one time each field of your form. If you need the `name` field in both of your forms you have to declare a `name` field in the two form builders.

Comment: @Jakumi yes the "some stuff" is for the rendering of my forms (collectionType). @.Hugo I know that I can only render one time each form and input, but I don't want to render the form on the first time. I only want to call it to create an array of inputs.